# Why doesn't .loc or .at extract a single value from dataframe to assign across another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to create a dataframe and assign a value from another dataframe's cell to the first dataframe's first column. i then want to assign another to all of the other columns.

when i run my code i am just getting the column headings.

here is the dataframe providing values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'M': [10, 20, 30],
               'N': [40, 50, 60]},
              index=['S', 'T', 'U'])

df1
```

it yields:

```
    M   N
S   10  40
T   20  50
U   30  60
```

how i want to create another dataframe and assign values to it as such:

```
testframe = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, 10, 1):
if i < 1:
    testframe[f'ProForma'] = df1.at['S', 'M']
        
else:
    testframe[f'per_{i}'] = df1.at['T', 'N']
```

i use this code to print the dataframe:

```
testframe.style.format('${:,.2f}')
```

and this is what i get:

```
ProForma    per_1   per_2   per_3   per_4   per_5   per_6   per_7   per_8   per_9
```

what am i doing wrong? i was expecting to get:

```
ProForma    per_1   per_2   per_3   per_4   per_5   per_6   per_7   per_8   per_9

  10         50      50      50      50      50      50      50      50      50
```

Comment: thank you Chrysophylaxs. will try initializing dataframe. i am confused by your last suggestion, though. isn't using the for loop assigning values to columns using an iterable?

Comment: hey Chrysophylaxs, initializing the dataframe did the trick! thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe is happening:

- You initialize `testframe` as an empty dataframe, so it has no index.
- You use `pd.DataFrame.at` to get the value being assigned to each column, which returns a scalar
- When you assign a column to a dataframe using a scalar, i.e. `df["col"] = 1`, that scalar is broadcast ("repeated") across the index and assigned to the new column for each row in the index.
- However, since your index is empty, broadcasting the scalar will result in it being repeated 0 times, so your dataframe is still empty.

You can solve your issue by initializing your `testframe` with an index, or by assigning to your column using an iterable (i.e. not a scalar).